# how to get session ID using customer_login and controller_action_postdispatch event in Magento

Tags: magento2

I want customer SessionID along with customer ID.

[image]

Comment: I want to access customer session ID in all the pages and on every event trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function __construct
(
   \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager $sessionManager
)

{
    $this->_session = $sessionManager;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $sessionID = $this->_session->getSessionId();
}
```

Comment: After hours of searching, I finally found this. Thank you for replying to your own question after you found an answer.